# Multivariate Inverse Transformation Sampling

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, sampling

### Summary

Given a multivariate density distribution, I use inverse transformation sampling to sample points from this distribution. While the first dimension exhibits the correct distribution, all other dimensions contain a slight, stable error.

### Details

My density distribution is given as a bilinear interpolation on the $([0-1], [0-1])$ rectangle. In the rest of this question, I use the following example:

$$
d(x,y)=\frac{4}{11}(2+x+2y-3xy)
$$

This results in the following density plot (brighter colors represent higher density):

[image: Density Plot]

The cumulative density function is

$$
cum(x,y)=\int_{0}^{x} \int_{0}^{y} d(px,py) dpy\ dpx = \frac{1}{11}(8xy+2x^2y+4xy^2-3x^2y^2)
$$

In order to sample from this distribution, I draw two samples $ux$ and $uy$ from the uniform $[0, 1)$ distribution and transform them to $x$ and $y$ as follows:

$$
cum(x, 1)=ux \\
x = 6-\sqrt{36-11ux}
$$

and
$$
cum(x, y)=ux \cdot uy \\
y = \frac{4+x-\sqrt{16+48uy+8x-40uy x+x^2+3 uy x^2}}{3x-4}
$$

The samples resulting from this transformation look reasonable (5000 samples in the following figure):

[image: Samples]

I tried to verify the result by approximating the cumulative density from the samples by simply counting how many of the samples have a smaller or equal x and y coordinate. Here are some results for 10 million samples. I report the analytic expected value and the results of two samplings. Digits are truncated:

```
                   i : 0.0   0.1   0.2   0.3   0.4   0.5   0.6   0.7   0.8   0.9   1.0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  analytic cum(i, 1) : 0.0   0.108 0.214 0.319 0.421 0.522 0.621 0.719 0.814 0.908 1.0
sampling 1 cum(i, 1) : 0.0   0.108 0.214 0.319 0.421 0.522 0.621 0.718 0.814 0.908 1.0
sampling 2 cum(i, 1) : 0.0   0.108 0.214 0.319 0.421 0.522 0.621 0.719 0.814 0.908 1.0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  analytic cum(1, i) : 0.0   0.091 0.185 0.280 0.378 0.477 0.578 0.680 0.785 0.891 1.0
sampling 1 cum(1, i) : 0.0   0.080 0.164 0.253 0.347 0.445 0.547 0.653 0.764 0.880 1.0
sampling 2 cum(1, i) : 0.0   0.080 0.164 0.253 0.347 0.445 0.547 0.653 0.764 0.880 1.0
```

Obviously, the cumulative density of the x-coordinates ($cum(i, 1)$) is almost exactly the analytic expression. On the other hand, there is a clear error in the y-coordinates ($cum(1, i)$). This error is stable across different samplings.

I cannot explain this slight error. Both the theoretical fundamentals and the implementation (with Mathematica) look sound.

Is there something I might have missed? Univariate sampling works perfectly as can be seen from the x-coordinates. However, multivariate sampling exhibits a slight error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error stems from the fact that you use $ux uy$ instead of just $uy$, which introduces a non-random $x$-dependent scaling factor for the uniform random $uy$ when sampling for $y$ and also the use of $\text{cdf}_{xy}$ instead of $\text{cdf}_{y|x}$. The remaining portion seems to be correct.

#### Inverse Transform Sampling

If $u \sim U(0,1)$, and $x \sim P_x$, then
$$\text{cdf}_x=\int_0^xP_xdx$$
$$\text{if}\quad \bar x = \text{cdf}_x^{-1}u\quad \text{then}\quad \bar x \sim P_x$$

#### The Ideal way

(Let $u_1$ and $u_2$ be the uniform random variables and $\text{cdf}$ be the cumulative distribution function.)
$$\text{cdf}_{xy}(x,1) = u_1$$
$$x =\text{cdf}^{-1}u_1 =6-\sqrt{36-11u_1}\quad\implies \quad x\sim \left(P_{x}=\int_0^1P_{xy}dy\right)$$
$$\text{cdf}_{y|x}(x,y) = u_2\quad \text{for} \quad x=6-\sqrt{36-11u_1}\quad\implies\quad \text{for given }x,\quad y\sim \left(P_{y|x}=\frac{P_{xy}}{P_x}\right)$$
$$\text{cdf}_{y|x} = \int_0^y P_{y|x} dy = \int_0^y \frac{P_{xy}}{P_x} dy$$
$$\therefore x,y \sim (P_{y|x}P_x=P_{xy})$$

#### The Incorrect Analysis

The initial part in your analysis is correct, and hence $x$ follows the marginal distribution it is supposed to follow, which is apparent from the fact that the values for $\text{cdf}(x,1)$ matches the expected values. The second part is faulty due to the $u_1$ term as follows:
$$\text{cdf}_{xy}(x,y) = u_1u_2\quad\text{for}\quad u_1=\frac{1}{11}(12x-x^2)=f(x)$$
$$\therefore \text{for given }x,\quad \frac{\text{cdf}_{xy}(x,y)}{f(x)} = u_2$$
So, because of the $f(x)$, we end up using a different $\overline{\text{cdf}}_{y|x}$ to sample $y$ instead of the intended cumulative density function given a particular $x$. To get the $\overline{\text{cdf}}_{y|x}$, we assume this to be coming from a faulty $\overline{P}_{y|x}$:
$$\overline{P}_{y|x} = \frac{\partial}{\partial y}(\overline{\text{cdf}}_{y|x})$$
$$\overline{P}_{y|x} = \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\frac{8xy+2x^2y+4xy^2-3x^2y^2}{12x-x^2} = \frac{-6xy+2x+8y+8}{12-x}$$
$$\therefore \overline P_{xy} = \overline P_{y|x}P_x$$
$$\overline{\text{cdf}}_{xy} = \int_0^y \int_0^x \overline P_{xy} dx dy$$
This, as solved in [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5Ey%20int_0%5Ex%20(-6xy%2B2x%2B8y%2B8)*(4%2F11*(3-0.5x))%2F(12-x)dxdy) is a very complicated function, but for our purposes, we can just take the $x$ integral from 0 to 1.
$$\overline{\text{cdf}}_{xy}(1,y) = -\frac{2}{11}y\left(\frac{31y}{2}-384(y-1)\coth ^{-1}(23)-21\right)$$
Evaluating this at different values of $y$ will give you the desired faulty values that you are getting in the sampling case above.

#### Addendum

I did a slight naming error in the Ideal way above, and I have now fixed it. Instead of taking $\text{cdf}_{xy}$ we needed $\text{cdf}_{y|x}$, which is what I assumed from that step onwards but wrote incorrectly. Corrected. That said,

> Consider we have chosen u1 such that x=0.5. Then, cdf(x,1) is 0.522.
> So, for any value 0≤y≤1, cdf(x,y) is smaller or equal to 0.522. But
> what if we sampled u2 greater than 0.522? Then, y would need to be
> greater than 1, which is invalid. That's why I thought that
> normalizing with cdf(x,1) would be necessary. Or, alternatively
> sampling u2 from [0,cdf(x,1))=[0,u1)

If, $u_1 \approx 0.522$, that would give us $x \approx 0.5$ from the marginal $x$ sampling (the $\text{cdf}_{xy}(x,1) = \text{cdf}_x = \int_0^x P_x dx$). That means, for $y$, we would set $\text{cdf}_{y|x}(0.5,y) = u_2$. The substituted $0.5$ already takes care of the normalization such that at $u_2=1$, we just need $y=1$

In our case, $\text{cdf}_{y|x} = (2y+xy+y^2-1.5xy^2)/(3-0.5x)$. Substitute $x=0.5$, to get $(2.5y+0.25y^2)/(2.75)=1$, which gives $y\in\{1,-11\}$.

Comment: I have to say, the numbers are pretty convincing. However, I still have trouble following the general idea. You state that $u_2=cdf(x,y)$. Here is what I don't get: Consider we have chosen $u_1$ such that $x=0.5$. Then, $cdf(x, 1)$ is $0.522$. So, for any value $0 \leq y \leq 1$, $cdf(x, y)$ is smaller or equal to $0.522$. But what if we sampled $u_2$ greater than $0.522$? Then, $y$ would need to be greater than 1, which is invalid. That's why I thought that normalizing with $cdf(x, 1)$ would be necessary. Or, alternatively sampling $u_2$ from $[0, cdf(x, 1))=[0, u_1)$.

Comment: @NicoSchertler See the addendum and the corrected "Ideal Way"

Comment: How would you do the equivalent of inverse transform sampling from a real-world joint pdf, where closed forms are not necessarily known?

Comment: @ijustlovemath I am not sure if I understand your question but you can perhaps use the empirical distribution if you have enough sampling, or assume a parametric model - fit the parameters and you now have a functional form to use for Inverse Transformation Sampling.

Comment: My question is based on how joint PDFs break a fundamental assumption of inverse transform methods; that they don't work on joint PDFs. I was wondering if there was an equivalent to inverse transform for these PDFs

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer to this question is good! However, I thought I would supplement it with some R code showing how to do the bivariate inverse sampling correctly with the distribution provided in the original question. I hope this helps future readers of this question.

```
# Bivariate Inverse Transformation Sampling

# Provided Bivariate Distribution
dis<-function(x,y){(4/11)*(2+x+2*y-3*x*y)}
dis<-Vectorize(dis)

# Heatmap of the true bivariate distribution
library(ggplot2)
data<-expand.grid(X=seq(0,1,0.01),Y=seq(0,1,0.01))
data$Z<-dis(data$X,data$Y)
ggplot(data, aes(X, Y, fill= Z)) + 
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "RdYlGn") + coord_fixed() +
  theme_bw()

# Now, note that we can find the marginal of X by just integrating y from 0 to 1
margX<-function(x){(-2/11)*(-6 + x)}
# Then, find the marginal cdf of X by integrating from 0 to x
margxcdf<-function(x){-1/11 * (-12 + x) * x}

# Then, using the marginal of X we can get the conditional distribution of Y|X by dividing the joint by the marginal
# Then integrate that with respect to y to get the conditional CDF of Y|X. (I did this in wolfram alpha)
condcdfY_X<-function(y,x){(y*(-2*(2 + y) + x*(-2 + 3*y)))/(-6 + x)}

# Now we can use inverse sampling to get the desired result. First, find the inverse of margXcdf and condcdfY_X
# I used wolfram alpha to solve for the inverse of the conditional (note: it has to be explicitly defined at x=2/3. See wolfram alpha for details)
margXcdf_inv<-Vectorize(function(u){6 - sqrt(36 - 11*u)})
condcdfY_X_Inv<-Vectorize(function(z,x){ifelse(x!=2/3,(2 + x - sqrt(4 + x*(4 - 20*z) + 12*z + (x^2)*(1 + 3*z)))/(-2 + 3*x),z)})

# Now to get a random sample from a uniform[0,1] for X & transform it
Xs<-runif(1000000)
Xs<-margXcdf_inv(Xs)

# Now to get a random sample from a uniform[0,1] for y 
Ys<-runif(1000000)
Ys<-condcdfY_X_Inv(Ys,Xs)

samples<-data.frame(X=Xs,Y=Ys)

# Now to plot the estimated bivariate distribution (using kernel density estimation) using the samples
library(MASS)
library(ggplotify)
library(gridExtra)
test<-kde2d(Xs,Ys,n=100)
hm_col_scale<-colorRampPalette(c("black","darkgreen","green","yellow","red"))(1000)
p1<-as.ggplot(~image(test$z,  
      col = hm_col_scale,
      zlim=c(min(test$z), max(test$z))))

p2<-ggplot(data, aes(X, Y, fill= Z)) + 
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "RdYlGn") +
  theme_bw()

grid.arrange(p1 + coord_fixed(),p2 + coord_fixed(),nrow=1)
```

Here are the final images produced by the code above:
[R code Final Images comparing sample distribution to true distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2q3I.png)

As you can see, the suggested solution by the accepted answer works correctly.